# PHP trimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if someone could help me with this looping array in PHP as I am still learning the language.

I need to loop into the 3-dimensional (3D) array below in order to:

- Check the `[room_type_id]` values and if its true to a specific value, I would return `[check_in_times]` array value for this same parent array.

**For example:**

```
if [room_type_ids] = 261
  I would need to return [check_in_times] = 1

if [room_type_ids] = 36
  I would need to return [check_in_times] = 2
```

My array is:

```
$myarray = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [check_in_times] => Array (
      [0] => 1
    ) 
    [room_type_ids] => Array (
      [0] => 261
      [1] => 281
      [2] => 283
      [3] => 292
      [4] => 296
      [5] => 365
      [6] => 381
      [7] => 387
      [8] => 389
      [9] => 730
    )
    [season_ids] => Array (
      [0] => 0
    ) 
  )
  [1] => Array ( 
    [check_in_times] => Array (
      [0] => 2
    ) 
    [room_type_ids] => Array (
      [0] => 36
      [1] => 38
      [2] => 300
      [3] => 318
      [4] => 336
      [5] => 889
      [6] => 897
      [7] => 728
      [8] => 745
      [9] => 747
    ) 
    [season_ids] => Array (
      [0] => 0
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$room = 261;
$checks = 0;

foreach ($myarray as $subset)
{
    if (in_array($room, $subset['room_type_ids']))
    {
        $checks = $subset['check_in_times'][0];
        break;
    }
}
```